# Prove an Enumeration of the Rationals Lemma

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D=\{ r_1,r_2,r_3,… \}=\{ 0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},… \}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. For $x \in [0,1]$, define the function $$f(x)=\sum_{r_n \le x} \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Lemma: For any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $x_0 \in (0,1)$, there exists a $\delta$ such that.

$$\sum_{x_0<r_n \le x}\frac{1}{2^n} \le \epsilon \quad if \space x_0<x<x_0+ \delta.$$

Attempt at the proof: Unfortunately I am only able to restate the hypothesis, and know I want to exert the existence of $\delta$ formally. Informally, I know $\delta$’s purpose is to minimize the sum by minimizing the amount of rationals that satisfy $x_0<r_n \le x$ (also forces to use terms further out to be used resulting in adding values that are very very small by density). I also know that $\epsilon$ should depend on $x$ and $x_0$ as the set is not in order of magnitude. My logic follows from the following “extreme” example:

Suppose there exists only 1 rational that satisfies $x_0<r_n \le x$ (neglecting density for the sake of an edge case). Then the sum $\sum_{x_0<r_n \le x}\frac{1}{2^n} \le \frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Now accounting for density of rationals and focusing on the problem rather than using an example to help understand, I become stuck on finding a path to take to prove the problem. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: There will be an infinite number of rationals between $x_0$ and $x$, no matter what you do.  Hint: choose $N$ big enough that $\sum\limits_{n>N} \frac1{2^n} < \epsilon$ and chose $\delta$ small enough none of your early enumerated rationals $q_1,q_2,\ldots q_{N}$ are in $(x_0,x_0+\delta)$